# Locked up (dealock) in @syncrhonized

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, mutex, deadlock

I have this piece of code which is executed from different threads. I cant find wheres the deadlock. Maybe Im not undestanding how @syncronized works

```
@synchronized(self) {
    NSLog(@"%@", self);
    NSLog(@"(%d) Aloha hermano blocked?" ,pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self()) );
    genres = [aContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Obj list fetch error: %@", error);
        exit(-1);
    }
    NSLog(@"(%d) Aloha hermano NO" ,pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self()) );
}
```

Heres the traces when the app gets locked:

```
2012-11-27 13:28:05.141 (15143) Aloha hermano blocked?
2012-11-27 13:28:05.146 (15143) Aloha hermano NO
2012-11-27 13:28:05.152 <STBConnection_0_9: 0xc676000>
2012-11-27 13:28:05.155 (15143) Aloha hermano blocked?
2012-11-27 13:28:05.161 (15143) Aloha hermano NO
2012-11-27 13:28:05.168 <STBConnection_0_9: 0xc676000>
2012-11-27 13:28:05.171 (15143) Aloha hermano blocked?
2012-11-27 13:28:05.178 (15143) Aloha hermano NO
2012-11-27 13:28:05.185 <STBConnection_0_9: 0xc676000>
2012-11-27 13:28:05.191 (1799) Aloha hermano blocked?
```

As you can see Im syncronizing always on the same object.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey I fixed it, the problem is that I was using the same ManagebObjectContext from different Threads. In that case the Apple docs say:

> If you share a managed object context or a persistent store coordinator between threads, you must  ensure that any method invocations are made from a thread-safe scope. For locking, you should use the NSLocking methods on managed object context and persistent store coordinator instead of implementing your own mutexes. These methods help provide contextual information to the framework about the application's intent—that is, in addition to providing a mutex, they help scope clusters of operations.

So, the code fixed looks like:

```
[aContext lock];
genres = [aContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error != nil) {
   NSLog(@"Obj list fetch error: %@", error);
   exit(-1);
}
[aContext unlock];
```